# Algorithm to express n! as product of powers of prime

Tags: c, algorithm

What could be the simplest and time efficient logic to express n! as product of powers of prime?

I am more interested to find the powers of prime so that I can know the numbers of factors.
As n! can be expresses as p1^e1 * p2^e2 * ... * pk^ek, where each p is a prime number, then the number of factors of n is (e1 + 1)*(e2 + 1)* ... *(ek + 1)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: All you need to do is find prime factorisation of every number in range 1..n. If you can factorise a single integer then you are done.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I was of the opinion that David Heffernan had just mentioned but thought there might be a more efficient way since it was a product of consecutive numbers. I am new to stackoverflow. Sorry if had broken some rules.

Comment: Once you find the first prime factor of n, the work you did on 1..n-1 does the rest with no more calculations needed.

Comment: @makmakjay45: You haven't broken any rules.  But there's an unspoken expectation that if one asks a question of the form "How do I do X?", one should accompany it with evidence that one is not simply asking "Give me the code for X".  (I'm not saying this is what you're doing, BTW.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Am I supposed to delete this post? Or How to I make your comment as the answer?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am really very sorry since I am new to the rules.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I apologise.

Comment: I've no idea whether or not this is the most efficient solution. So I can't really answer with confidence. Leave the question here and see if you get a good answer. No need to hurry.

Comment: lol. you are new to stackoverflow, clearly asking a homework question, yet you know to use @username replies in comments. Anyway, +1 for an intresting question.

Comment: at a glance I would take inspiration from the sieve of Eratosthenes, interleaving (so to say) the search for primes `2..n` with "counting" how many times the "current" (in the run) prime divides exactly all the "deleted" numbers ... at first I thought its complexity would be that of the sieve, but it is not, since for each "deleted" number you have to add the "time" you need to "reduce" it until it is no more divisible exactly by the prime. I am not able to existamate it on the fly but it should be greater than O(n) (a lot greater than,...?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most efficient way to find the prime factorisation of `n!` that I know of is counting how often each prime appears as a factor in `n!`. Obviously, no prime larger than `n` appears, so let `p <= n` be a prime.

Among the numbers `1, ..., n`, there are

```
q1 = floor(n/p)
```

multiples of `p`. Among these, there are

```
q2 = floor(q1/p) = floor(n/p²)
```

multiples of `p²`. Among these, there are

```
q3 = floor(q2/p) = floor(n/p³)
```

multiples of `p³`. Etc. So the exponent of `p` in the prime factorisation of `n!` is

```
q1 + q2 + q3 + ...
```

(An `a = p^k*b`, with `b` not divisible by `p` contributes `k` to the exponent, and appears in the `k` lists corresponding to the counts `q1, ..., qk`.)
We can succinctly write a function for that:

```
unsigned long long factorial_exponent(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long p) {
    unsigned long long exponent = 0;
    do {
        n /= p;
        exponent += n;
    }while(n);
    return exponent;
}
```

That uses `floor(log n/log p) + 1` divisions, so, if the primes not exceeding `n` are known, that contributes approximately

```
log n * ∑ (1/log p + 1) ≈ 2n/log n
       p≤n
```

divisions and additions to the total work. (Note: since most of the primes `≤ n` are `> √n`, and for primes `p > √n` obviously `q2 = 0`, it is faster to calculate their exponent directly: `n/p`, that reduces the number of divisions needed by about half.)

Finding the primes not exceeding `n` is best done with a sieve, if you already have a good implementation, the [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) does it in O(n) or O(n/log log n) operations (depends on the implementation, but for feasible ranges, `log log n` can be considered a constant), otherwise use the Sieve of Eratosthenes, it's simple to implement and finds the primes not exceeding `n` in - again depending on the implementation - O(n*log log n) or O(n) operations.

The total work for that algorithm is dominated by finding the primes (but for feasible `n`, the contribution of the determination of the exponents is still not negligible).

On the other hand, the work needed for finding the prime factorisation of each `k ≤ n` of course depends on the algorithm used for that. Using trial division for that would result in a total work of about `c*n^1.5/log n` - I haven't done anything to determine the constant `c`, and depending on details, you may have a factor of `log n` in the numerator or denominator, but it's basically `n^1.5`. A better method of finding the factorisations would be first finding the smallest prime factor [or any prime factor] with a modification of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, again in O(n*log log n) operations, and then use that to find the factorisation. You can store the factorisations and then, when processing `k` with the known prime divisor `p`, look up the factorisation of `k/p`, or generate the factorisation on the fly by recursively looking up the known prime factor `q` of `k/p`, then of `k/(p*q)` etc. until the factorisation is complete - that is much simpler to handle if the known prime factor is always the smallest.

On average, the prime factorisation of `k` contains `≈ log log k` terms, so that method would lead to O(n*log log n) overall complexity. But the constant factors in this method are considerably larger than in the first, so even if the prime-finding gives the same complexity, the first is faster.

Comment: If I were qualified to comprehend the answer, I expect I'd want to mod up.  The current SO rating system is dysfunctional - this answer should give much more than it will.

Comment: @BlankXavier Trust me, it is worth an upvote ;) Yes, some (way too many) answers get fewer upvotes than they deserve, but others get more. Maybe in the long run it cancels.